# What is the elegant way to find a number in a string?

Tags: python, string, int

I want to get a number from a string, as in `font: bold 13 Arial` --> `13`. What's the most elegant and Pythonic way to do this?

However, I also need the "context" of the number. I want to change it, then rebuild the original (e.g. `font: bold 13 Arial` --> `font: bold 14 Arial`)

Comment: Regular expressions

Comment: try to use regex "\d+"

Comment: @David Robinson you should post that as an answer so it can get accepted.

Comment: I'm on a phone- someone else should take it so they can do it properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you the number as a string

```
>>> import re
>>> num_regex = re.compile(r'\d+')
>>> num_regex.findall("font: bold 13 Arial")
['13']
```

From there you can pull out the first element and cast to int.

Similarly, you can use `search` instead of `findall`

```
>>> num_regex = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
>>> matcher = num_regex.search("font: bold 13 Arial")
>>> matcher.groups()
('13',)
>>> matcher.group(1)
'13'
```

Since you now say you want to replace the contents of the number, you could do it using the `sub` method:

```
>>> num_regex = re.compile(r'\d+')
>>> num_regex.sub('14', "font: bold 13 Arial")
'font: bold 14 Arial'
```

And finally, if you want to do something like increment the current value by 1, and **like** having very unreadable code then this should do the trick:

```
import re

source = "font: bold 13 Arial"
print re.sub(r'\d+', str(int(re.findall(r'\d+', source)[0])+1), source)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
font: bold 14 Arial
```

This is the more usable approach, but **note**, there is no error handling and input sanitization.  In this form, use with caution. :P

```
num_rex = re.compile(r'\d+')

def increment_str_number(source):
    return num_rex.sub(str(int(num_rex.findall(source)[0])+1), source)
```

And lastly, to replace all of the numbers, assuming there is more than one in your source (though just one will work too):

```
import re
num_rex = re.compile(r'\d+')

def increment_str_number(source):
    nums = set(num_rex.findall(source))
    for num in nums:
        num = int(num)
        source = re.sub("%s" % (num), "%s" % (num + 1), source)
    return source
```

**INPUT**
font: bold 13 Arial 15

**OUTPUT**
font: bold 14 Arial 16

Comment: The idea is to _increment_ the number, not replace it, so you have to retrieve the number itself as well as the surroundings, but I suppose i could use split for that.

Comment: @Glycan: see my edit I did right when you were typing that comment.

Comment: I'm not exactly going to put malicious input in my own code x)

Comment: It doesn't have to be malicious.  Try it with input that doesn't contain a number.  Or with input that contains two numbers.  It really depends on how solid it is based on your use case.  If you will only ever use it when you have a number, and only one number that you want to increment then it should work just fine.

Comment: You can use a function in `re.sub` `re.sub('\d+', lambda m:str(int(m.group(0))+1),'font: bold 13 Arial')`

Comment: What about substituting all the numbers?